# Add values of objects with equal attributes, transforming into a single object

Tags: javascript

Hello I have the following problem: I have an array of objects that I need to check if the name and method are being repeated, if so add the attributes of their values and transform into a single object with the values added

```
let array = [
  {name: visa, method: 1, value: 55}, 
  {name: visa, method: 1, value: 78}, 
  {name: master, method: 2, value: 143}, 
  {name: visa, method: 1, value: 18}
];
```

objective:

```
let array = [
  {name: visa, method: 1, value: 151}, 
  {name: master, method: 2, value: 143}
];
```

Try:

```
   let array2 = [];
   for (let j = 0; j < array.length -1; j++) {
    const element = array[j];
    const element2 = array[j + 1];
   
      if(element.name === element2.name && element.method === element2.method){
      
        element.value += element2.value;

        array2.push(element);
      } 
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  There are multiple ways to do it, but it seems like a loop over the original array to populate the new array seems like a simple approach.

Comment: I just put my attempt at a look

Answer (score 1):

What I did here is store the the results (by name) in an object, and convert it into an array of values at the end.

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 55 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 78 },
  { name: 'master', method: 2, value: 143 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 18 }
]

const arrayByName = {}

array.forEach(curr => {
  if (!arrayByName[curr.name]) {
    arrayByName[curr.name] = curr
    return
  }

  arrayByName[curr.name].value += curr.value
})

console.log(Object.values(arrayByName))
```

or maybe using `reduce` and `Object.values()`

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 55 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 78 },
  { name: 'master', method: 2, value: 143 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 18 }
]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return { ...acc, [curr.name]: { ...curr, value: acc[curr.name] ? acc[curr.name].value + curr.value : curr.value } }
}, {}))
```

Currently, there's two operations here: Accumulation of the sum through a loop and the `Object.values`. I'm curious if anyone can do it in a single loop though, that would be great! Ping me, I'm also curious

Update:

Solved it using a single loop and a hashmap of indices. I think this is faster than the rest of my answer above as this has only a single operation and just looks up the index of the existing name using the hashmap

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 55 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 78 },
  { name: 'master', method: 2, value: 143 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 18 }
]

const nameIndices = {}
const result = []

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const curr = array[i]

  if (nameIndices[curr.name] === undefined) {
    nameIndices[curr.name] = result.length
    result.push(curr)

    continue
  }

  result[nameIndices[curr.name]].value += curr.value
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can use [Array#Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here

```js
let array = [
  {name: "visa", method: 1, value: 55}, 
  {name: "visa", method: 1, value: 78}, 
  {name: "master", method: 2, value: 143}, 
  {name: "visa", method: 1, value: 18}
];

const reducedArray = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const existing = acc.find(x => x.name === curr.name && x.method === curr.method)
  
  if(!existing) acc.push(curr)
  else {
    existing.value += curr.value
  }
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(reducedArray)
```

*Note : You can update the find method to match only one parameter (only the name for example) or more if you want*

Comment: I love you, thanks so much my friend! That's exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Glad to help ! Do not hesitate to mark the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running too many loop or condition you can simply use this following code to solve your problem.

```js
const array = [
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 55 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 78 },
  { name: 'master', method: 2, value: 143 },
  { name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 18 }
]

// array to track the names
let cardTypes = []

// Main result array
let result = []

array.forEach((obj) => {
  let condition = cardTypes.includes(obj.name);
  if(!condition){
    cardTypes.push(obj.name);
    result.push(obj)
  }else{
    let index = result.findIndex((r_obj => r_obj.name == obj.name));
    result[index].value += obj.value
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [
  {name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 55},
  {name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 78},
  {name: 'master', method: 2, value: 143},
  {name: 'visa', method: 1, value: 18}
];

let r = Object.values(array.reduce((a,c) => {
  (a[c.name]??={...c, value:0}).value += c.value; return a;
}, {}));

console.log(r);
```

Note: this assumes that each 'name' property (e.g. 'visa') always has the same method property (e.g. 1).